How to Search Recursively in Command Line Excluding a Specific Directory?
I usually use dir /s <keyword> in the command line to find files by name and wildcards, but the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Containers\BaseImages directory always clutters my search results. I've disabled Windows Sandbox and Containers with:
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containers-DisposableClientVM" -NoRestart
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containers" -NoRestart

However, I need to re-enable them occasionally with:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containers-DisposableClientVM" -NoRestart
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Containers" -NoRestart

Deleting C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Containers\BaseImages\432cb2cc-0c12-49c7-a0bc-a144b37316f1\BaseLayer.vhdx from the command line seems impossible.
Is there a way to search a directory recursively from the command line while excluding a specific path using CMD batch, PowerShell, VBScript, or JScript?
P.S. for those who end up here, take a look at the ES Everything CLI es.exe, fuzzy finder fzf.

Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

@DavidPostill I have tried developing a PowerShell script, but it is not ideal. so I didn't want to clutter the question and confuse the readers. Would it help if I post that on a GitHub Gist and post a link here?

A simple answer would be to enter the following.
dir /b /s <keyword> | find /v "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Containers\BaseImages\"

You are not really skipping. Instead, you are just filtering.

I have git installed on my Windows 10 computer. You can download git from here. I installed using the default settings. This gives me access to Unix/Linux commands. So on my computer, I can enter the following in a Command Prompt window.
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash"
find $PWD -ipath /c/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Containers/BaseImages -prune -o -iname "<keyword>" -print
exit

Here I assume you are searching from your current directory. I also assume <keyword> is the filename or filenames you are looking for, which may include wildcards. For example, *.exe.
I suppose the above commands could be reduced in a single line, as shown below.
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash" -c 'find $PWD -ipath /c/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Containers/BaseImages -prune -o -iname "<keyword>" -print'

If you add C:\Program Files\Git\bin to the end of the path, then you could shorten the line, as shown below.
bash -c 'find $PWD -ipath /c/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Containers/BaseImages -prune -o -iname "<keyword>" -print'


but this would still waste time and computation on searching those folders, right? How can I really avoid searching that folder at all.

You cannot. Even with powershell where you can filter it, it will still process that folder. That's just how it works.

Foad: I updated my answer to show a way you could avoid searching that folder at all.
